# Geometric series starting from -n

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do I find the following series:

$$\sum^n_{k = -n}ar^k$$

I'm not sure how to manipulate the standard geometric series to get the desired result.

Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: *Hint:* $\sum\limits_{k=-n}^n f(k) = \left(\sum\limits_{k=-n}^{-1}f(k)\right)+\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^nf(k)\right)$ and $\sum\limits_{k=-n}^{-1}f(k)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n f(-k)$

Comment: Alternatively $\sum\limits_{k=-n}^n f(k) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{2n} f(k-n)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write $$\sum^n_{k = -n}ar^k=\sum^n_{k = -n}ar^{k+n}r^{-n}=r^{-n}\sum^{2n}_{m = 0}ar^m$$
by defining $m=k+n$